# How to efficiently return rows belonging to the top N most frequent elements

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partition

Let's say I have some table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id INT, usr CHAR, age INT );
INSERT INTO test (id, usr, age) VALUES (1, "a", 10); 
INSERT INTO test (id, usr, age) VALUES (2, "a", 29); 
INSERT INTO test (id, usr, age) VALUES (3, "a", 12); 
INSERT INTO test (id, usr, age) VALUES (4, "b", 6); 
INSERT INTO test (id, usr, age) VALUES (5, "b", 5); 
INSERT INTO test (id, usr, age) VALUES (6, "b", 4); 
INSERT INTO test (id, usr, age) VALUES (7, "c", 8); 
INSERT INTO test (id, usr, age) VALUES (8, "c", 18); 
INSERT INTO test (id, usr, age) VALUES (9, "d", 12);
```

I want to return only rows in which usr is one of the top N most frequent usr. for a value of N=2, the result would be

```
[(1, "a", 10), (2, "a", 29), (3, "a", 12), (4, "b", 6), (5, "b", 5), (6, "b", 4)]
```

I would like this to be returned as a table, so that I can apply more queries on it.

In terms of dialects, I'm running this on duckdb, postgres, and bigquery.

I can get this done with a group by plus an inner join

```
select *
from <MY TABLE> as t1
inner join (
    select usr, row_number() over() as usr_rank
    from (
        select 
            usr, 
            count(*) as usr_cnt
        from <MY TABLE>
        group by usr
        order by usr_cnt desc
        limit 10
    )
) as t2
on t1.usr = t2.usr
```

but that seems inefficient. Ideally, I would like to do this using partitions, where I rank each partition by its size, and assign that value as a column to every row in that partition. I've tried something like this:

```
select
    *,
from (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over ( partition by usr order by count(*) desc) as usr_rank
    from <MY TABLE>
)
where usr_rank < N
```

But I'm told that I can't use an aggregation operator inside the over statement, and I also suspect this isn't even doing what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't see a way to get around selecting twice from the same table since you want to return everything from that table.

```
with user_ranks as (
  select usr, rank() OVER (Order BY COUNT(*) DESC) as usr_rank
  from test
  group by usr)
select t.*
from test t
join user_ranks r
  on t.usr = r.usr
where r.usr_rank <=2;
```

You can substitute rank() with row_number() but just depends how you want to handle ties.

However, if this is something you plan to repeat, then consider creating an update script to add another column to that table and run as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your first query; by using subquery;

And for N = 2 it can be written as

```
SELECT id, usr, age
FROM (
  SELECT id, usr, age,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY usr ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS user_rank
  FROM test
  GROUP BY id, usr, age
) myquery
WHERE user_rank <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a query to identify the user segment you want to use and then filter by it in your where clause.

```
WITH userFrequencyFilter AS 
(SELECT
    usr
FROM dataset.test
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY count(*)
LIMIT 2)

SELECT * FROM `dataset.test`
WHERE usr in (SELECT * FROM userFrequencyFilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select rec.* from (
  select array_agg(t) recs
  from your_table t
  group by usr
  qualify row_number() over(order by count(*) desc) < 3
), unnest(recs) rec
```

if applied to sample data in your Question - output is

[image]